# UICollectionView changing cell top and bottom distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I am pretty new in IOS Development.I using code from this tutorial [Creating a Paged Photo Gallery With a UICollectionView](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/).You can get code from this [link](https://github.com/timd/UICollectionViewGallery).Here i want to change image top and bottom distance in collection view cell. How i can do that ?
Here is the code for collection view cell:

```
-(void)setupCollectionView {
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CMFGalleryCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
    [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.dataArray count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CMFGalleryCell *cell = (CMFGalleryCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *imageName = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setImageName:imageName];
    [cell updateCell];

    return cell;

}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return self.collectionView.frame.size;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Data methods
-(void)loadImages {

    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Assets"];
    self.dataArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath error:NULL];

}
```

Code for CMFGallary.cell is :

```
#import "CMFGalleryCell.h"

@interface CMFGalleryCell()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end

@implementation CMFGalleryCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CMFGalleryCell" owner:self options:nil];

        if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
            return nil;
        }

        if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
            return nil;
        }

        self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)updateCell {

    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Assets"];
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", sourcePath, self.imageName];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filename];

    [self.imageView setImage:image];

    [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

}

@end
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly into the question. Links can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Can you Copy/Paste the code in your CMFGalleryCell.m please ?

Comment: you can see it above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the collection view flow layout for add insets like:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topMargin, leftMargin, bottom, right);
```

or implement

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                        layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(topMargin, leftMargin, bottom, right);
}
```

Comment: No it is not changing the cell with images of collection view...please help